# Regex for Sentences in python

Tags: python, regex

> I have one more Query
>
> here is two sentences

`[1,12:12] call basic_while1() Error Code: 1046. No database selected`

`[1,12:12] call add() Asdfjgg Error Code: 1046. No database selected`

`[1,12:12] call add()`

`[1,12:12]`

`Error Code: 1046. No database selected`

now I want to get output like this

`['1','12:12',"call basic_while1"]` , `['1','12:12', 'call add() Asdfjgg']`,`['1','12:12', 'call add()']`,`['1','12:12']`,`['','','',' Error Code: 1046. No database selected']`

> I used this `r'^\[(\d+),(\s[0-9:]+)\]\s+(.+)` this is my main regex then as per my concern I modified it but It didn't help me
>
> I want to cut  everything exact before "Error Code"
>
> how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that in a single regular expression, the pattern is a bit unwieldly: `(?:^\[(\d+),(\s?[0-9:]+)\](?:\s+(.+?)\s?)?(?:Error Code:.*)?$)|(?:()()()(Error Code:.*$))`

```
>>> s = """[1,12:12] call basic_while1() Error Code: 1046. No database selected
... [1,12:12] call add() Asdfjgg Error Code: 1046. No database selected
... [1,12:12] call add()
... [1,12:12]
... Error Code: 1046. No database selected"""
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(?:^\[(\d+),(\s?[0-9:]+)\](?:\s+(.+?)\s?)?(?:Error Code:.*)?$)|(?:()()()(Error Code:.*$))')
>>> for line in s.split('\n'):
...     print(pattern.match(line).groups())
...
['1', '12:12', 'call basic_while1()']
['1', '12:12', 'call add() Asdfjgg']
['1', '12:12', 'call add()']
['1', '12:12']
['', '', '', 'Error Code: 1046. No database selected']
```

I'm a big fan of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) to try interactively create regular expressions.

Comment: it helps , but I just modified my ans , please ans it @Daniel

Comment: One last Query I added above there , just check it out , this one is last , what if there only "Error code " sentence , that time I don't want to refuse/skip it . Thanks for the help

Comment: r'(?:^\[(\d+),(\s?[0-9:]+)\](?:\s+(.+?)\s?)?(?:Error Code:.*)?$)|(?:(Error Code:.*$))'        , now what should I change in get only Error string like [ Error Code: 1046. No database selected] , otherwise [" "," "]  only , I know its different scenario , is possible to do this with this Regex ? because it can be done by different Regex

Answer (score 0):

basically you asked to get everything before the "Error Code"

> I want to cut everything exact before "Error Code"

so it is simple, try: `find = re.search('((.)+)(\sError Code)*',s)` and `find.group(1)` will give you `'[1,12:12] call add() Asdfjgg'` which is what you wanted.

if after you got that string you want `list` that you requested :

`desired_list = find.group(1).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(',',' ').split()`

Comment: you are right , but is it work if there is no "Error Code" ?, that's why I modified my question, and add more sentences

Comment: I edited my answer so it will work even if there is no "Error Code" in the sentence - try it and tell me what you think

Comment: bro, I understand the syntax but I am not able to enter this into my code , can you please give me example with code?, and i know it helps so let me mark it as "accepted "

Comment: its good, but splits everything , not give a output like you mentioned there @NoobforSQL

Comment: agree!  @Coder it is working but not give me output like I mentioned there